# JS for loop types: why is one version output integer and another string?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, output

I am doing an online course JavaScript.
I am leraning right now the for loops and there are two types it is about:
for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
for (let i in students)
See the code.
One is giving an output with student number 1-8 and the other gives an output like 01,11,21,31 aso.
why?

```
"use strict"

const students= ["Melanie","Leni","Matilda","Niels","Anke","Juergen","Lilli","Hans"]

console.log("=========================================")
console.log("Variante 1\n")

for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Teilnehmer ${i+1} Name lautet: ${students[i]}`)
}

console.log("\n=========================================")
console.log("Variante 2\n")
for (let i in students) {
      console.log(`Teilnehmer ${i+1} Name lautet: ${students[i]}`)
}
```

I expected the code to deliver the same output.
If i remove the +1 it is the same.

Comment: `students.forEach((student, i) => console.log(\`Teilnehmer ${i+1} Name lautet: ${student}\`))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object property names are always strings. In the first version of your code, you are using a number in the loop, and JavaScript converts the number to a string when accessing the object property. Because it's a number, `i + 1` will be a numeric addition.

In the second version, your code uses the property names directly, so they're strings in the loop. Thus `i + 1` means string concatenation.

Comment: Wow ok, thank to you @pointy.
Thats not easy to understand as a newbie. :-D
But it is important to understand the differnce and I am thankful for your explanation.
I wish you a merry christmas and a happy new year!

Comment: @NielsvonDaake It's important to be aware that Arrays are also objects, and when enumerated, the keys come out as `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"` etc... (i.e. strings).

Comment: @Spender yes, thank you. The  array numbers I understand. That an array always begin at 0 instead of 1
Thats why I wantes to manipulate the number given so it starts with 1 instead of 0 in the listing. :-)

Comment: I now addes the parseInt :
console.log(`Teilnehmer ${parseInt(i)+1} Name lautet: ${students[i]}`)
Like this it works. But is there another solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript

Comment: @NielsvonDaake you could use `${+i + 1}`

Comment: @epascarello
Thanks. That was also helpful. I tried it out now with: 
console.log(`Teilnehmer ${i*1+1} Name lautet: ${students[i]}`) and it work too. Great, what a lesson today! Thanks to you all! and a Merry Christmas!

Comment: omg one more solution. What a great day for me :-)